# What is the “entry price” in relation to tariffs?

Tags: definition, tariffs

I see the term “entry price” and “price entry system” in relation to tariffs.

What do these means?

For example this document: https://ageconsearch.umn.edu/bitstream/10095/1/sp06go22.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entry price system (EPS) is a [EU-specific term](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.foodpol.2008.06.005) relating to their food import tariffs, more specifically to fruits and vegetables. It's a somewhat complicated system designed to strongly discourage imports below a certain price. This is a summary from 2009 paper:

> The EU protects growers of 15 kinds of selected fruits
>   and vegetables against international competition not
>   only by the means of ad valorem tariffs of up to 20%,
>   but also by the EPS. The EPS came into effect on 1
>   July 1995, replacing the former RPS. Analogous to a
>   minimum import price, the EPS is designed to restrict
>   imports below the product-specific, politically
>   designated EP plus ad valorem tariff (Table 1). If the
>   EP is undercut, an additional specific tariff is levied,
>   which proportionally varies depending on the gap
>   between the product’s actual import price and the EP.
>   When the EP is undercut by 8% or more, the
>   maximum specific tariff, referred to as the maximum
>   tariff equivalent (MTE), of up to 80% of the EP is
>   charged. For example, the EPS is applied to oranges
>   during the EU orange harvest season in the time period
>   December 1 to May 31. The MFN tariff for oranges
>   seasonally varies between 3.2% and 16.0% whereas
>   the MFN EP remains constant at a level of 354 €/t. If
>   oranges are exported to the EU at a price of 336.3 €/t,
>   the EP is undercut by 5%. This implies that the
>   exporter has to pay an additional specific tariff of 17.7
>   €/t which is equal to the gap between the import price
>   and the EP. If the entry price for oranges is undercut
>   by 8% or more, an additional specific tariff at the level
>   of the MTE of 71 €/t is charged. [...]
>
> [image]
>
> Monitoring compliance with the EPS faces the
>   difficulty that a large share of fruit and vegetable
>   imports in the EU is on commission, implying that the
>   import price is not determined until the product is sold
>   in the EU market. Therefore, the EC calculates a
>   synthetic import price, the standard import value
>   (SIV). Fruit and vegetable prices, surveyed for each
>   product and export country individually, are collected
>   on representative fruit and vegetable wholesale
>   markets in all EU Member States. The daily SIVs are
>   calculated as a weighted average of collected
>   wholesale market prices, less a marketing and
>   transportation margin and applied tariffs.
>   The EPS can be circumvented (both legally and
>   illegally), so that some product is finally sold at prices
>   below the EP (García-Álvarez-Coque, 2002).
>   According to information from importers, illegal
>   circumvention (e.g. based on false invoicing) is more
>   prevalent in small-scale trading, particularly between
>   related trading partners. Storage can offer a means of
>   legal circumvention, as storable products can be
>   imported at any time while customs clearance is
>   delayed until some later date when the SIV is above
>   the EP. Once cleared at a favourable SIV, the product
>   can be sold later on EU markets at any price (Cioffi
>   and del' Aquila, 2004).

There were some [2014 changes](https://www.freshfruitportal.com/news/2014/04/23/qa-european-commission-explains-new-entry-price-system-for-fruit-veg/) (not covered in that quote).